# Sqlite Statement not showing items in iPhone

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have fired the given query

`SELECT id,Date,Time,Brief,Main FROM iChapter WHERE Subject = 'a' AND Date BETWEEN 'Jan29,2012:Sunday' AND 'Feb04,2012:Saturday'`

on sqlLite for finding the number of chapters between the given date,

however it is not showing any data for the above query.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite date and time functions: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html